# gmaps4rails hide show sidebar

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

So, if markers are hidden on the map, their sidebar item stays visible.  I read through the entire gem, and I didn't see any functionality for also hiding the corresponding sidebar element.  Anyone have a clue on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function hide(category) {
  var regEx = new RegExp("[" + category + "]")
  for (var i=0; i<Gmaps.map.markers.length; i++) {
    if (Gmaps.map.markers[i].cat) {
      if (Gmaps.map.markers[i].cat.match(regEx)) {
        Gmaps.map.hideMarker(Gmaps.map.markers[i]);
        $('a#' + Gmaps.map.markers[i].id).closest('li').hide();
        Gmaps.map.visibleInfoWindow.close();
      }
    }
  }
  // == clear the checkbox ==
  document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = false;
}
```

did that... with a corresponding show method.  works nicely!

Answer (score 0):

To customize gmap4rails you need to study and go through all api or methods provided in support. Also you may hide show sidebar using params to below given method

```
  def gmaps4rails_sidebar
    "#{self.name} #{self.gps}"
  end
```

Also more links are given here https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki. Please refer.

Comment: Hmmm.  Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question.  I'm well aware of how to customize the sidebar.  The example you show is actually quite outdated.  You can now (and should) build everything from the controller - https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Controller .  I'm looking specifically to hide a single entry in the sidebar, if that single marker is hidden from the map.